# more "where" constraints in generic class is possible?

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I have an interface (since I could n't think up a way to set up properties for what I retrieve from DB query calls) that is defined like this,

```
interface class IData
{
public:
   void Set(int i);
   int Get();
};
```

and I have a generic class defined like this

```
generic<typename T, typename U> where T:IsomeInterface public ref class MyClass{};
```

I would like to add "where U:IData" into the above declaration of MyClass but I am stuck now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same as C#.. like this:

```
generic<typename T, typename U> 
    where T:IData
    where U:IData
public ref class MyClass { 
    };
```

..etc.

Comment: Thank you, but if I add `gcnew()`,I have to add a comma after `where U:IData`